# Plotting polynomials roots

Tags: python, performance, numpy, data-visualization, matplotlib

**NOTE:** See follow up to this question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164790/plotting-polynomial-roots-with-density)

I created a simple python script to plot quadratic, cubic and quartic polynomials with integer coefficients between -4 and 4. It uses numpy to find the roots for the polynomials and matplotlib for the actual plotting of the points. Because I want to plot all possible polynomial with integer coefficients between -4 and 4 I figured I needed to do a recursive function with a loop. However if I'm not mistaken this will give a time complexity of \$O(n!)\$.

```
import matplotlib

# Use Qt4Agg because otherwise matplotlib crashes on my computer running Arch Linux
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

min_degree = 2
max_degree = 3
colours = []

def polynomial_scatter(ax, min_x, max_x, min_degree, max_degree, cur_degree, coeff):
    global colours

    if cur_degree <= max_degree:
        for c in range(min_x, max_x):
            new_coeff = coeff + [c]
            polynomial_scatter(ax, min_x, max_x, min_degree, max_degree, cur_degree + 1, new_coeff)
            if cur_degree >= min_degree:
                roots = np.roots(new_coeff)

                # check if no possible solution exists
                if len(roots) == 0:
                    continue

                # the real part of the roots will be our x values, the imaginary parts will be our y values
                x, y = zip(*[(t.real, t.imag) for t in roots])

                # scatter the roots for this polynomial with a colour corresponding to the degree of the polynomial
                ax.scatter(x, y, c=colours[cur_degree - max_degree], alpha=.5, s=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    colours = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, max_degree - min_degree + 1))
    polynomial_scatter(ax, -4, 4, min_degree, max_degree, 0, [])
    plt.savefig("plot.svg", format="svg")
    plt.show()
```

Here are some pictures showing the result:
[image]
[image: quartic polynomial]
[image: cubic polynomial]

if I set max_degree to 5 it takes between 7-15 hours on my computer which is very long. Perhaps there is a way to implement multithreading.

How can I improve the performance of the polynomial_scatter algorithm?

Comment: I think there are some symmetries in the coefficient space you're exploring. If all coefficients are multiplied by a constant, the roots stay the same, right? This would mean that any solution (except for the trivial solution) is plotted at least twice; e.g. after negating coefficients. So you could choose to loop over `range(0,max_x)` for the last coefficient. Also I think that coeff[0]==0 implies a lower degree, correct? If so, the function should either call itself or calculate roots.

Comment: Expanding on the previous comment: if the last coefficient is 0, you're actually solving a lower degree polynomial (ignoring the trivial solution). That implies that you could also loop over `range(1,max_x)`. This should be 55% faster already.

Comment: @mvds that is an interesting optimization. Not sure how to implement that into a recursive function however.

Comment: in pseudo code: `range(cur_degree==max_degree?1:min_x, max_x)`

Comment: @mvds I might implement that, but I switched to C++ and have another performance problem now. Here is the new post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164790/plotting-polynomial-roots-with-density

Answer (score 1):

I know that you subsequently [posted c++ code for this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/164790/120114) and that post has answers, one of which is accepted.

I did notice that the code above references the global variable `colours`. This may be seen as bad programming style because it can cause side effects that may be challenging to detect. Alternatively, function parameters could be used, or else a  class with a class/data/instance member.